# Rails associations with string causing AssociationTypeMismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have the following in my DevicePurchase model -

```
has_one :coupon_code, primary_key: 'coupon_code', foreign_key: 'name'
```

The app Im working on associates a DevicePurchase with a CouponCode by the coupon's name (a string, i.e. "SummerPromo123") and not the idea. The association I added above looked to be working, however when I tried `DevicePurchase.last.update(...)` I received this -

```
DevicePurchase.last.update(coupon_code: 'yLVDnw')
  DevicePurchase Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "device_purchases".* FROM "device_purchases" ORDER BY "device_purchases"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: CouponCode(#70224191762780) expected, got String(#70224129222500)
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:224:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/associations/has_one_association.rb:25:in `replace'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:78:in `coupon_code='
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `public_send'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:29:in `block in assign_attributes'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `each'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:230:in `block in update'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:203:in `block in transaction'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `within_new_transaction'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:203:in `transaction'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:327:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/activerecord-4.0.12/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:229:in `update'
  from (irb):55
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
  from /Users/ryangrush/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@myautobrain/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'2.2.4 :056 >
```

I found a few StackOverflow answer for that error but I think the problem is with my association.

** update **

If I run `DevicePurchase.last.update(coupon_code: CouponCode.last)` I get the following error -

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM "coupon_codes" WHERE ("coupon_codes"."name" = 1188 AND "coupon_codes"."id" != 1188) LIMIT 1
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 1: ...FROM "coupon_codes"  WHERE ("coupon_codes"."name" = 1188 AND...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "coupon_codes"  WHERE ("coupon_codes"."name" = 1188 AND "coupon_codes"."id" != 1188) LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 1: ...FROM "coupon_codes"  WHERE ("coupon_codes"."name" = 1188 AND...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Show the full code that throws error. That code will help us to help you. :D

Comment: ok its updated now.

Comment: try `DevicePurchase.last.update(coupon_code: Coupon.find_by_name('yLVDnw'))` .. I mean give it the actual `Coupon` object.. tell me

Comment: I tried that, getting a new error now. I added the error above.

Comment: Ok so your model has some mess. Show the schema.rb content of the coupons table ?

Comment: yeah, I am following your error.

Comment: Can you tell `name` column type and `coupon_code` types in your DB?

Comment: they're both `:text` types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue is, You got the association name and column name same. So, When you try `DevicePurchase.last.update(coupon_code: 'yLVDnw')`, Rails thinks you will be passing it an `CouponCode` object, not the "string" value as you have now. That's why the error you got. But if you rename the association like below, you should be fine:

```
has_one :coupon,
  primary_key: 'coupon_code',
  foreign_key: 'name',
  class_name: 'CouponCode'
```